# Finding the last cluster of a file

Tags: c++, winapi, deviceiocontrol

I'm trying to find the last cluster of a target file and read the binary data off of it. I started off with CreateFile() and used that result in DeviceIoControl() with control code FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS.

```
hfile = CreateFile(result,                          
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,                           
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          
        NULL);

RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER retrievalBuffer;  
const DWORD Clusters = 1000;
const DWORD rpBufferSize = sizeof(RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER) + (2 * (Clusters - 1) *sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
BYTE output[rpBufferSize];
STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER startVcn;
startVcn.StartingVcn.QuadPart = 0;

returns = DeviceIoControl(hfile,
            FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,
            &startVcn,
            sizeof(startVcn),
            &output,
            sizeof(output),
            &bytesReturned,
            NULL);
```

So I don't really know what to do next. If I display `LARGE_INTEGER Lcn` from the `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` I get a huge number which represents the current extent. I also have a switch error case which comes up as `NO_ERROR` so I am assuming that all the cluster data was read successfully. What can I do which the Lcn number to help me find the last cluster of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retrievalBuffer` should be a pointer:

```
RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER *retrievalBuffer = (RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER *) output;
```

So the last extent starts at

```
DWORD lastExtentN = retrievalBuffer->ExtentCount - 1;
LARGE_INTEGER extentLcn = retrievalBuffer->Extents[ lastExtentN ].Lcn;
```

The extent size is

```
LARGE_INTEGER extentClusters = retrievalBuffer->Extents[ lastExtentN ].NextVcn
    - lastExtentN ? retrievalBuffer->Extents[ lastExtentN - 1 ].NextVcn
                  : retrievalBuffer->StartingVcn;
```

Thus, last logical cluster number (LCN) of the file is:

```
LARGE_INTEGER lastLcn = extentLcn + extentClusters - 1;
```

Now you can open logical volume using `CreateFile()` and read this cluster using `ReadFile()`

NOTE: you need to check `extentLcn` against `-1` to support sparse files.

Comment: I tried you method and for some reason at LARGE_INTEGER lastExtentN = retrievalBuffer->ExtentCount - 1; it says that ExtentCount is suppose to be unsigned long? Also in the extent size did you mean to use NextVcn as opposed to Vcn?

Comment: There seems to be another error now because you are trying to subtract a DWORD from a Large INTERGER when trying to find out the extent size. I'm a little bit lost in a logic.